# Is the charset component mandatory in the HTTP content-type header?

Tags: http, http-headers

An `HTTP` request might have the `Content-Type` header:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
...
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
...
```

**Is there circumstances where the `charset` component is mandatory? in case, when?**

Example of possibles `Content-Type` headers, not necessarily correct:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Type: charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf8
Content-Type:
```

**Standard info:**

EDIT NOTE: It seem this reference is obsolete, RFC 7231 is the correct version now, as suggested by @RobbyCornelissen.

The Standard say rather little about this (or maybe I am looking in the wrong place): https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> 14.17 Content-Type
>
> The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the
>   entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method,
>   the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET.
>
> ```
>    Content-Type   = "Content-Type" ":" media-type
> ```
>
> Media types are defined in section 3.7. An example of the field is
>
> ```
>    Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4
> ```
>
> Further discussion of methods for identifying the media type of an
>   entity is provided in section 7.2.1.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [RCF 7231, Appendix B.  Changes from RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#appendix-B):

> The default charset of ISO-8859-1 for text media types has been
> removed; **the default is now whatever the media type definition says**.
> Likewise, special treatment of ISO-8859-1 has been removed from the
> Accept-Charset header field.  (Section 3.1.1.3 and Section 5.3.3)

So it depends on the default character set / encoding for the given media type. You can look up the [media type registry with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), for example the [application/xml media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/xml), which links to [RFC 7303 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7303#section-3):

> As many as three distinct sources of information about character
> encoding may be present for an XML MIME entity: a charset parameter,
> a BOM (see Section 3.3 below), and an XML encoding declaration (see
> Section 4.3.3 of [XML]).  Ensuring consistency among these sources
> requires coordination between entity authors and MIME agents (that
> is, processes that package, transfer, deliver, and/or receive MIME
> entities).

> The use of UTF-8, without a BOM, is RECOMMENDED for all XML MIME
> entities.

So no, it's not mandatory, but if omitted, it depends on the specific media type how you can detect it.